# unable to filter when i open the screen it will always empty flutter but when type some thing in textfield it shows data in listview

Tags: flutter, listview, filter

i am having some issues tried but unable to resolve it. i am working on filter so have textfield and listview on screen. when i open the screen the listview is always empty. but when i type some thing in textfield it will search and show the data. but on load listview shows no data.

here is my code.

```
import 'package:emis/colorschemes.dart';
import 'package:emis/single_healthfacility_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_easyloading/flutter_easyloading.dart';
import 'database_helper.dart';
import 'models/healthfacilities.dart';

class HealthFacilitiesListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HealthFacilitiesListScreen({super.key});
  @override
 _HealthFacilitiesListScreenState createState() =>
    _HealthFacilitiesListScreenState();
 }

  class _HealthFacilitiesListScreenState
  extends State<HealthFacilitiesListScreen> {
bool isLoading = false;
List<Healthfacilities> _allealthfacilities = [];
List<Healthfacilities> _filteredHealthfacilities = [];

Future<void> _fetchHealthFacilities() async {
final db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;
EasyLoading.show(status: 'Loading...');
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = await db.rawQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM ${DatabaseHelper.dbTableHealthfacilities} ORDER BY officename ASC");
print(results);
setState(() {
  _allealthfacilities =
      results.map((map) => Healthfacilities.fromJson(map)).toList();
});
EasyLoading.dismiss();
 }

 void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
   List<Healthfacilities> results = [];
  if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty || enteredKeyword == "") {
  results = _allealthfacilities;
  } else {
  results = _allealthfacilities
      .where((hf) => hf.officename
          .toLowerCase()
          .contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
      .toList();
}

  setState(() {
    _filteredHealthfacilities = results;
  });
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _fetchHealthFacilities();
//_filteredHealthfacilities = _allealthfacilities;
}

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: headerAppBar,
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      centerTitle: true,
      title: const Text(
        "Health Facilities",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
            },
            icon: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7)),
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: Icon(Icons.home),
                ))),
      ],
    ),
    body: Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
          topRight: Radius.circular(40),
        ),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
        child: isLoading
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              ))
            : Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Search',
                      filled: true,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          width: 0,
                          style: BorderStyle.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: buttonRed,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(
                            Icons.search,
                            size: 28,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _filteredHealthfacilities.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final healthfacility =
                            _filteredHealthfacilities[index];
                        print(healthfacility.officename);
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                //border: Border.all(),
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                            child: ListTile(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          HealthFacilityScreen(
                                              healthfacility:
                                                  healthfacility),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                leading: const Icon(
                                  Icons.health_and_safety,
                                  size: 35,
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                ),
                                title: Text(
                                  healthfacility.officename,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Text("DO Mirpurkhas"),
                                trailing: const Icon(
                                    Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined)),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: bottomFooter());
 }
```

}

solution and help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your listview.builder you mentioned the _filteredHealthfacilities which is already empty when it loads first time try to assign all the data to it when you fetch the data and as you type your data will filtered out and shown to user.

Comment: unable to get uncommented in initstate but still unable to get it

Comment: just do this 

setState(() {
  _allealthfacilities =
      results.map((map) => Healthfacilities.fromJson(map)).toList();
_filteredHealthfacilities =_allealthfacilities ;
});

 in your existing _fetchHealthFacilities method

Comment: thanks you sir very much saved my life.

 Future<Healthfacilitybasicprofile?> _fetchallservices() async {
    final db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = await db.rawQuery(
      "SELECT * FROM ${DatabaseHelper.dbTableHealthFacilityBasicProfile} WHERE hfid = ?",
      //where: 'hfid = ?',
      [widget.healthfacility.hfid],
    );
    if (results.isNotEmpty) {
      return Healthfacilitybasicprofile.fromJson(results.first);
    }
    return null;
  }

i want to fetch single record n to show in textfield via of model class.

Comment: Actually not getting it in this comment section can you add as separate question ?

Comment: If previous answer i helpful then please mark as accepted and upvote the answer.

Comment: How to fetch single record from sqflite in flutter and map it to model class